# Shortest path between two locations

Tags: google-maps

I made a google map applications that shows the user location and near by restaurants now i want to draw the shortes path between the user location and the restaurant he chooses..can you help me please

Comment: go through [directions-simple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

Comment: please try to ask question that has something to check and something to recommend use google to find some similar stuff like this.

Comment: Google Maps API doesn't provide the shortest path, it typically provides the fastest path.

Comment: You can ask for alternatives and pick the shortest one: alternatives=true param in the request

Answer (score 0):

The directions API will typically return the fastest route, but this isn't necessarily the shortest path. You can, however, get the shortest path from the API with a little bit of work:

Let's say your user already has selected the restaurant and you already have the user's location. The directions API will return one route or multiple routes depending on if there are available alternative routes and if you have set the parameter to true. Each route is broken down into legs. The best way for you to get the shortest route would be to sum up all legs in each route contained in the routes array. The route with the lowest total when you sum up the distance of each leg in the route will be the shortest route.

I hope this helps!